# Where are all the statusbar icons stored so that I can change them?

Tags: notification-bar

I have a rooted phone and would like to change my ugly status icons to the ICS ones...

I used [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qcnVtbXkubGliZXJ0eS50b29sYm94cHJvIl0.) app to do so but I could change only the battery icon. When I wrote to the developer, he replied that the icons do get replaced but my phone is still using the old ones from another location where they might be stored too as backup or something I guess.

How do I find this alternate place where they are stored?

Is there a fixed predefined place for it?

Here is a snap of the reply from the developer -

***"*** *Changing icons and files in your system is something that Android was never meant to be capable of doing and because of this it makes it difficult to work on every Android device. The themes and icons provided in the app were pre-created and meant to work on the majority of devices. The app searches your system for matching icons and if no icons match in your system it does it’s best to find the best match. You can see what icons will be changed when you go to install a theme or icon pack.*

*Even after the icons are changed the theme might not work with your system. Many devices have unused icons used in other devices. **On many of the problems we hear about the icons actually did change but your system used icons from a different location.** If you have the T-Mobile Theme Chooser and are using a theme or your system is using icons from a different location then the theme will not work. Also, if your device isn’t deodexed the theme will not work.* ***"***

---

### Edit

---

I read about odex and deodex from [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-odex-and-deodex-in-android-complete-guide/). Can I install only the deodexed file of the statusbar instead of the complete rom? and how do I deodex it?

Answer (score 2):

The Status bar icons are found in SystemUI.apk  which is placed in /system/app/ folder. Use [APK tool guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1891686) and decompile the SystemUI.apk file and follow this guide to make [some mods](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2203166) as you wish.

I have used this apk to change the signal icons, mobile data icons (H, E etc), Battery 1% Modification etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the stock ROM for your phone? If not, try a custom ROM like [CyanogenMOD](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) or [AOKP](https://plus.google.com/105080186717848173196/about).I've had far better results with themes running a custom ROM.

Comment: no! there is no cm for my phone! I have a micromax a52 and the xda developers,or rater any developers couldnt root the phone for 6 long months! they could not find the boot.img file at all! they got it through some undisclosed ways/sources and finally rooted it! so basically a simple root itself was quite difficult to achive and so no custom rom is yet available! and i dont think CM would ever even be!

Answer (score 0):

The icons are stored in the `/system/framework`, inside an apk called `framework-res.apk` which is referenced by `framework.jar` file.

**Caveat Emptor:**

- Interfering with it could cause the handset to boot-loop due to
  mismatched discrepancies, if the apk was recompiled, the
  `framework.jar` file could have difficulty in loading the resources
  (hence part of the filename has this `-res.apk`).

Also, it would need to be re-signed with the system ROM's certificate which would be tricky to achieve if the keys are not present.